# Microsoft Graph API - 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm working to integrate Microsoft Graph with a Rails web application. We're trying to send multiple email messages via Graph, but every now and then we get a `503 Service Unavailable` with the following headers and body:

Response headers:

```html
{
  "content-type": [
    "text/html; charset=us-ascii"
  ],
  "server": [
    "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0"
  ],
  "date": [
    "Wed, 30 May 2018 22:05:31 GMT"
  ],
  "connection": [
    "close"
  ],
  "content-length": [
    326
  ]
}
```

Response body:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Service Unavailable</TITLE>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <h2>Service Unavailable</h2>
    <hr>
    <p>HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.</p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

We use the `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail` call to send hundreds of outlook emails. After sending roughly 100-200 emails with the Graph API we get the `503 Service Unavailable` error. **This is problematic when we have to send 1000+ customized emails** since it is unclear to me how we could properly **handle the error without knowing how long to wait before retrying and other Graph API request**.

I'm wondering if anyone has run into a similar issue before. I've read about something similar along the lines of client throttling ([Microsoft Graph API - Throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47654844/microsoft-graph-api-throttling)), but in this post, they're getting `409` (with a `retry-after` header), not `503`.

Based on the [Graph documentations](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/errors), we're supposed to receive a JSON object that may contain a `Retry-After` header. However, as shown above, we're neither getting the `Retry-After` header nor a JSON object for the `503` error.

Comment: Sorry that you are running into this issue. This is certainly not a case of throttling. Can you share the region where your client is calling to Microsoft Graph? Also, it would be helpful to know the time range of this failure.

Comment: @SriramDhanasekaran-MSFT: On **2018-05-30**, our server in **Oregon** tried at 8:16:21pm UTC / 9:07:43pm UTC / 10:05:42pm UTC (other attempts as well). Our server in **Virginia** sent a few tries on the same day, 12:43:39pm UTC / 3:04:14pm UTC / 10:22:03pm UTC. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: We also have the same issue ... any update ?

Comment: After monitoring our servers for a while, it looks like we get them during the mornings (9-12pm EDT). We just got a few of those 503 errors a few minutes ago (11.15-11.20am EDT). Any news on this issue @SriramDhanasekaran-MSFT?

Comment: @SriramDhanasekaran-MSFT: To follow up on the issue, we got the same error a few hours ago but this time we're receiving a different message. We're now correctly receiving a **JSON** for both **503/504** server errors, but both of them return the error message **UnknownError** (instead of HTML with "Service Unavailable" or "Gateway Timeout" text). Let me know if this info helps fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As an update here. In future for any 500 error messages, you are best to raise these as service issues as per the instructions here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/support

Have a paid Azure subscription?
Visit the Azure Admin Center.
https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/newsupportreq

Have a Premier support contract for Microsoft 365?
Visit the Microsoft 365 Admin Center and use the Support menu.
https://admin.microsoft.com/