# Microsoft Graph API Daily Limitation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph API to upload my excel file to Onedrive and convert it to PDF. My service has a lot of traffic so I want to know about the daily limitation of Microsoft Graph API? How many requests I can send to Microsoft Graph per day?

Somebody already asked about `Throttling` on Stackoverflow, but I'm not really sure about Daily Limitation API?

```
10 minutes - 10000 requests

1 day (1440 minutes) - 1440000 requests
```

Is that correct?

`Throttling is done per user per app. The threshold is 10000 requests every 10 minutes.`

[Microsoft Graph API - Throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47654844/microsoft-graph-api-throttling)

Answer (score 5):

With Microsoft Modern APIs, you will never know what is the current throttling limits. The main reason for this is because they change depending on a lot of factors and I don't believe they are ever disclosed.

As a best practice you should have error handling on your App so it's smart when that happens.
Whenever your app is affected by throttling you will get a HTTP error code 429 response and you should back-off immediately and retry after a bit. From the documentation, however I never actually noticed that when I was dealing with throttling with Sharepoint a year ago, is a "Retry-after" header that will tell you how much to wait.

The documentation actually has a good explanation that you can find fairly easy here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling